# Getting system problem detected on startup, clicking Report does nothing

Tags: 14.04, system

So on every startup now I get a system problem detected window, but when I click report it just closes and nothing happens. Is there a command I can run to see the error, or something I need to do to fix this issue? Thanks for any help! Running 14.04

Answer (score 3):

Type this command to get rid of the issue:

`sudo rm -rf /var/crash/*`

Then, reboot, it should solve your problem.