# "System problem detected" after every login but no reports in /var/crash

Tags: 18.04

For a couple of weeks I have been getting the "System problem detected" every time I log in after booting.

Solutions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/695561/18599) say delete the files in /var/crash but there are no files here on my system.

I do **not** want to turn crash reporting off or send them automatically.

I **do** want to know what in my system may be causing problems.

How can I find out which part of my system is causing this problem despite non-existent reports or, if the report alert itself is a bug, how can I prevent the system problem alert for this non-issue while continuing to receive system problem alerts for real issues?

**Update:** This behavior has stopped without my intervention but I will leave the question open in case others experience the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best advice would be find the problem and fix it,

Without determining the problem, you should be able to disable the popup, (but you would be better off finding th source of the "problem")

`vim /etc/default/apport`

> ```
> # set this to 0 to disable apport, or to 1 to enable it
> # you can temporarily override this with
> # sudo service apport start force_start=1
>
> enabled=1 # <-- Set this to 0
> ```

Or `sudo systemctl stop apport.service` to stop it (also could `disable`).

If you do want to try and find out what is causing the issue, you can insepect the logs, what I find useful and has helped me track down *most* errors:

Look for any service files that aren't starting correclty

```
systemctl --failed
```

Look through the journal of the current boot for any error messages

```
journalctl -p 3 -b
```

Comment: Thanks, but i believe you've misread my question. Both quotes of mine are saying the same thing. You may have accidentally read a "not" in the first quote.

Comment: @authentictech you might also try `systemctl --failed` I'm not entirely sure what triggers the popup tbh

Comment: The problem stopped by itself soon after your comments so I couldn't find anything wrong but I think those two comments would probably be useful. I don't think there is a chance of a better answer so if you want to add the two comments to the answer I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: @authentictech updated

Comment: This `systemctl --failed` help me to find the reason why I was getting the prompt on each login (+1)