# Where the error report is saved

Tags: apport

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04 (upgraded from 19.10, and that upgraded from 18.04).

Even the fact I use exactly the same Operating System inside 3 desktop PCs and 1 laptop... I have a problem only in one of the desktop PCs.

Each time I TURN ON that PC, I get the classic error message:

> Ubuntu is detected an error in a program. Do you want to send a report about this?

I have read about that errors are saved inside a file inside the folder: *var/crash*

But... I have been searching in that folder and... Nothing! That folder is absolutely empty (even the fact I have set the *See hidden files* ON).

So... Where those reports are saved? How can I know which program is given the error(s)?

Comment: Have you tried `gnome-logs` ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't let me to see any before the 1-2 minutes the present time (and the error was before that time).

Comment: I discovered that "gnome-logs" is useful if we used it inmediately the error is present.So, I could see the "logcheck" and "blueman" apps (I don't have any clue about those apps) had problems related with some lost files and folders. I decided to eliminate both apps and... Now I don't have any error when I turn on the PC! But... I don't know if this could be considered a "final solution"...

Comment: There's a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1121941/829559).

I also found a guide for [Log files locations](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files#2-log-files-locations) on Ubuntu website

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mido!!!

Comment: No problem. Have a good day !